# mongoDB - eBAY style categories

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, categories

I am wondering how would you store a list of categories and sub categories in mongoDB for people to sell items.

This is how I was going to do it, but then I when I think about it it wont work.

here is why

```
{"category":"Fashion",
"Sub-Categories":
[{
   "subcat_name":"Female Clothing",
    "Sub-categories":[{"subcat-name":"Dresses"},{"subcat-name":"Shirts"},{"subcat-name":"Business"}]
}]
}
```

As you can see there are two levels of sub categories which means it may get confussing to update.

Could someone tell me the best way to do category lists in mongoDB like ebay and gumtree

Comment: Have you read through the wiki information on [Trees in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB)?  There are some common pattern examples there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition collection (so, the collection that describes which categories and sub categories exist) should be structured as follows :

```
db.categories {
_id: <Category ID, unique code or ObjectId>,
name : <Human readable category name>,
subCategories : [
    {
        subCategoryCode : <Sub category ID, local unique code>,
        name : <Human readable sub category name>,
        <additional sub category data>
    }
],
<additional category data>
}
```

And your items :

```
db.items {

_id : <Item id>
name : <Human readable item name>
category : {
    categoryId : <Category ID>,
    categoryName : <Human readable category name>,
    subCategoryId : <Sub category ID>,
    subCategoryName : <Human readable sub category name>,
},
<additional item data>
}
```

Run this schema through all your common use cases and you'll find you're very rarely in a position where you need to query both collections for a single common operation. The data duplication is intentional and needs to be managed (meaning you'll have to bulk update items in a certain category if you update the category name). If you cannot live with that for performance or practicality reasons you can only store the names and maintain an app local id->name cache in your application to facilitate category lookups without querying the database.

Questions? comment

Comment: Hi I have an small issue, and that would be , the subCategoryId how do i make them an ID like _id

Comment: Well you can simply generate an ObjectId but any ID will work since it only has to be unique within the main category. Could even be the escaped, lower-case version of the sub category name string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make your array like a linked list, you must have a column for parent category.

the parent category column points at the index of the (obviously) parent category, i think you   get my point.

now you can retrieve this information using recursion

here is you sample array

```
index    name               parent
  1      fashion   
  2      female clothing      1
  3      dresses              2
  3      shirts               2
```

so by this you can create a dynamic category with just simple structure

Comment: Sorry could you give a simple sample

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoDB's syntax but i hope the idea can get you somewhere